# npm install aborted on EC2 instance - Cannot get stack trace in GC

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, npm-install

I am trying to install react application on EC2 instance.

when ever I do `npm i` in frontend folder, it gives me garbage collector error. However, I was able to successfully run `npm i` for backend (`nodejs`). I am running node js server in the same instance using **"forever"**.

The error:
[image: Garbage collector error]

Any Idea what has to be changed? I am new to AWS.

Answer (score 0):

I think I already met a similar issue, I solved it by using a most recent version of node... try to set the nodejs version from your codebuild to nodejs v12

Maybe you can try to allocate more memory too